# "I want him arrested." Is "arrested" a participle that act as an adjective modifying "him"?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrases, parts-of-speech, participles

A participle act as an adjective. But adjective mostly come before noun. This sentence only has pronoun. And "arrested" comes after pronoun. If "arrested" does not act as an adjective, What is its function in this case?

Answer (score 1):

There is a small group of verbs that can take an object followed by an adjective: examples include **make**, **get** and **consider**. According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/want), **want** is one of these words, and it also specifies that the adjective can be a past participle or a present participle:

> I want these curtains **cleaned** - *past participle*
>   I don't want him **hanging** around here - *present participle*

Looking at your sentence:

> I want him arrested

**him** is the object of the verb, and **arrested** is a past participle that describes the state you want him to be in.

Comment: It may be helpful to think of this as short for "I want him **to be** arrested." Regardless, this is a good and correct answer.